# Rolling over multiple columns returning one result in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Im struck over rolling a window over multiple columns in Pandas, what I have is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4],'B':[5,6,7,8]})
def test(ts):
    print(ts.shape)
df.rolling(2).apply(test)
```

However the problem is that `ts.shape` prints `(2,)` and I wanted it to print `(2,2)`, that is include the whole window of both rows and columns.

What is wrong about my intuition about how rolling works and how can I get the results im after using Pandas?

Comment: It starts with the first column, takes the first two observations and then the next two and when the first column is finished, it goes to the second one. You can see that by returning a float value from the test function and printing `ts`  instead of its shape.

Comment: Yes but how can i get the results i want using pandas then?

Comment: Well, you are using a custom function so it won't be vectorized. Why not just use a loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little hack - get numeric columns length by [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) and use this scalar value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4],'B':[5,6,7,8], 'C':list('abcd')})
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  5  a
1  2  6  b
2  3  7  c
3  4  8  d

cols = len(df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns)
print (cols)
2

def test(ts):
    print(tuple((ts.shape[0], cols)))
    return ts.sum()

(2, 2)
(2, 2)
(2, 2)
(2, 2)
(2, 2)
(2, 2)

df = df.rolling(2).apply(test)
```